# Give feedback to 3D models (Prefabs) using HoloLens

Tags: augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am currently researching how can we give feedback (Text, Speech, Graphics, etc) to 3d models (Prefabs) using HoloLens 2? This is my research topic and I have limited knowledge about AR, XR and learning on my own by going through many research papers, videos and so on.

Consider below example:

If the designer is designing a prototype of a computer mouse as a 3D model and he needs the opinion of a customer about it. So he gives that 3D model to the customer and then customer wants to give feedback about some parts of the mouse to the designer using HoloLens. will the designer able to do so?

So could anyone please tell me whether it is possible to give feedback to 3D models using HoloLens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Interactable component](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html#how-to-configure-interactable) provided by [MRTK-Unity](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/README.html) can respond to input such as touch, hand rays,  speech, etc and funnel these interactions into events and visual theme responses.

You can import your 3D model into Unity and add Interactable components to each part of the model,  then customize the [Visual Theme](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/VisualThemes.html#custom-theme-engines) of the Interactive components. Visual themes define what transforms and materials your model will update in different states. After that, your model will feedback in real-time when the customer interacts with it. Besides, if you like, you can also write your own code to customize the object on how to work after receiving the [event](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html#events).

To complete the above steps, you need to know some basics about Unity. It is recommended that reading the official [Unity documentation](https://unity.com/learn) and understand the basics of Mixed Reality from here: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html

Comment: ...Thanks a ton for such a valuable answer. I am going through tutorials for Unity and trying to learn MRTK. Once I have a good idea about all these things, I will start playing through it.